# Communicate directly between custom Chrome devtools panel and Chrome Extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My question is: is there a way to communicate directly between my custom Chrome DevTools panel and my Chrome Extension's content script? Right now, it seems like I need to use the background script as a mediator between the content script and the devtools panel.

I tried using a custom window event:

// in the dev tools panel

```
let event = new Event('suman-dev-tools', {
  value: 'foo'
} as any);


window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

// in the content script

```
window.addEventListener('suman-dev-tools', function(ev){
  console.log('my devtools panel has spoken:', ev);
});
```

but that doesn't seem to work - it looks like I can't use window events to communicate between the two things. Must I use the background page to communicate between devtools page and content script?

Comment: Try opening a port to your content script via chrome.runtime.connect

Comment: wOxxOm the answer from @Deliasz is nice if you didn't know that trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned the best practice is to use background script as a message broker.

But there is one more way to run code in content-script directly from devtool panel: [devtools.inspectedWindow.eval](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#method-eval) with `useContentScriptContext: true` allows you to evaluate code in the content-script scope.

```js
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('<your code>', {
    useContentScriptContext: true
}, function(result) {
    // result of the execution
});
```

Comment: I might use this, thanks....using the background script as a message broker is not the easiest thing, especially since I need to match devtools windows to the matching content scripts

Comment: this worked, thanks a ton. And it worked with an injected script (executeScript) also. The only gripe I have, is that the TypeScript typings seem to be wrong for the the `inspectedWindow.eval` method.